# How does Mac OS High Sierra connect to https if port 443 is closed

Tags: macos, firewall, nmap

I have Mac OS High Sierra firewall turned on and set to "block all incoming connections except those required for basic Internet services such as DHCP, Bonjour and IPsec."

I was looking at an nmap scan of localhost of 443.

```
$ nmap -p 443 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-12 16:07 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00040s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
443/tcp closed https
```

This nmap scan shows that port 443 is closed.
How does the browser connect to https for websites.  When I visit one, I see the https:// and the green lock showing certificate compliance is green as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 443 is the default port for **incoming SSL connections**. It is not only not used for **outgoing connections**, but in fact browsers use different outgoing ports for each connection - see this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1055281/do-web-browsers-use-different-outgoing-ports-for-different-tabs) on Superuser.

Note also:

- Blocking of outgoing and incoming connections is configured
  separately on every firewall I've ever used - you yourself wrote that you set your firewall to

> block all incoming connections except those required for basic Internet services such as DHCP, Bonjour and IPsec

without mentioning anything about outgoing connections.

- `nmap` scans for open ports for incoming connections.